# To trim lines based on line number in perl

Tags: perl, line

My Perl file generates the text file which usually contains 200 lines. Sometimes it exceeds 200 lines (For example 217 lines). I need to trim off the rest of the lines from the 201st line. I have used the counter method to trim the exceeded lines. Is there any other simple and efficient way to do this?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename1="channel.txt";
my $filename2="channel1.txt";
my $fh;
my $fh1;
my $line;
my $line1;
my $count=1;
open  $fh, '<', $filename1 or die "Can't open > $filename1: $!";
open  $fh1, '>', $filename2 or die "Can't open > $filename2: $!";

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{ 
  chomp $line;
  chomp $line1;
  if($count<201)
     {
        print $fh1 "$line\n";
     } 
     $count++;
}
close ($fh1);
close($fh);
```

Comment: So where's the code? You are not being clear, what should happen to the remainder of the lines? Throw them away or start a new file etc?

Comment: head -n 200 some_file

Comment: @GerhardBarnard. The part of the code is in a big Perl file. Will share that chunk. Yes, need to discard the rest of the lines.

Comment: @xxfelixxx Thanks. Will try this.

Comment: @xxfelixxx why do you need to go outside of perl tools to perform this task if perl can do it?

Comment: You don't of course...but the OP hasn't given us any code...so by far the easiest thing to do is just pipe the output to head.

Comment: @xxfelixxx Sure thing, but what if OP does not have a *nix environment? :)

Comment: @nandeeshv  I hope you forget the `$.` for getting the current line.  Instead of making the variable count

Comment: @nandeeshv see edit in my answer below writing back to original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already mentioned in my comment, this is short version of that comment If you actually trying to trim the file you can use the Perl One Liner instead of writing the whole code

```
perl -pe 'last if($. == 201);' input.text >result.txt
```

> -p used for process the file line by line an print the output
>
> -e execute flag, to execute the Perl syntax

With Perl script you can do this also

```
open my $fh,"<","input.txt";
open my $wh,">","result.txt";

print $wh scalar <$fh> for(1..10);
```

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted. Do I need to include this statement as a system command? system("perl -pe 'last if($. == 201);' input.text >result.txt "); Also, I have to write it into same file.

Comment: @nandeeshv no, this is a standalone onliner. so you run this from commandline instead of a script, if you really want to run this from a script you can call it as system, or use backticks, but that kindoff defeats the purpose of oneliners, as you call perl twice, once by calling the script and within the script you call perl again.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard. Thanks. I followed your code. It worked well. I was wondering whether I can use this one-liner in system command or backtick to reduce the number of lines. Nevertheless, I don't have to optimize too much. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @nandeeshv you can, though it is not appropriate. You are calling perl with the script, then within the script you call perl again. The idea of oneliners is to avoid scripts, if I have to say it in so many words.

Comment: @nandeeshv Don't do like that. If you are writing the Perl Script you go with Gerhard Barnard answer.

Comment: @nandeeshv I have edited my answer you can try this method also in your script.

Answer (score 2):

**xxfelixxx** already gave you the correct answer. I am just changing my earlier posted answer, to clean up your code and to **write back** to the original file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array;
my $filename="channel.txt";
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open > $filename: $!";

while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    last if $. > 200;
    push @array, $line;
}
close($fh);
open $fh, '>', $filename or die "Can't open > $filename: $!";
print $fh @array;
close($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to keep your own counter, perl has a special variable `$.` which keeps track of the input line number.  You can simplify your loop like so:

```
while( chomp( my $line = <$fh> ) ) {
    last if $. > 200;
    print $fh1 "$line\n";
}
```

[perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) - Search for **INPUT_LINE_NUMBER**.

Comment: `$.` starts at 1, not 0.  Try this to see:  `seq 1 10 | perl -ne 'print "$. : $_";'`

Comment: Is there any way I can modify the same file instead of writing to another file?

Comment: @nandeeshv  Well, yes, you can read into memory the first 200 lines in the same way, then reopen that file for writing and dump those 200 lines back into it.  But why?

Comment: No reason to `chomp` and then `print` with a newline: `while (<$fh>) { last if $. > 200; print $fh1 $_;}`. (Unless it's meant to be pedagocical.)

Answer (score 0):

To write back to the original file: `input.txt` without using redirection:

```
perl -pi.tmp -we "last if $.>200;" input.txt
```

where

```
-i : opens a temp file and automatically replaces the file to be 
     edited with the temporary file after processing (the '.tmp'
     is the suffix to use for the temp file during processing)
-w : command line flag to 'use warnings'
-p : magic; basically equivalent to coding:
     LINE: while (defined $_ = <ARGV>)) {
         "your code here"
     }
-e : perl code follows this flag (enclosed in double quotes for MSWin32 aficiandos)
```